# Conditionals and arrayjobx

Tags: conditionals

I am struggling with the use of conditionals, I have a basic example given below that will output the table included.

The code starts by defining `\myletterA` as the A character, and an array called `\test` as A,B,C. I have a function called `\indenterer` that I call inside my table loop below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\tand{&}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myletterA}{}
\newcommand{\myletterwriter}[1]{\renewcommand\myletterA{#1}}
    \myletterwriter{A}

\newarray\test
\newcommand{\indenterer}{%
    \readarray{test}{A&B&C}%writes A,B,C to array test
    \checktest(1)%reads the first value
    \cachedata%returns the value last read by \checktest
    \myletterA%returns the value stored i.e. A
    \ifx\cachedata\myletterA%
    a% \true case
    \else%
    b% false case
    \fi%
}

\newcounter{it}
\begin{tabular}{ll}%
\hline%
  \setcounter{it}{1}%
  \whiledo{\theit<4}{%
    {\indenterer} Y \tand z \\%
  \stepcounter{it}%
  }%
\end{tabular}

space
    \checktest(1)
    \cachedata
    \myletterA

\end{document}
```

The output lines of the table should display `\cachedata\myletterA_ Y Z` where the _ is either an a or b. So my question is why is this code always executing the false case (note the letter b instead of a) even though both `\cashdata` and `\myletterA` expand to give the same result?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\newcommand{\myletterwriter}[1]{\renewcommand*\myletterA{#1}}`?

Comment: Inside the `\indenterer`, just before `\ifx` add `\show\cachedata\show\myletterA` and you'll see `\cachedata` is just a "macro", while `\myletterA` is a "long macro".

Comment: Thanks you two. I did not know about long vs not long, I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy. `;-)` With

```
\newcommand{\myletterwriter}[1]{\renewcommand\myletterA{#1}}
```

the macro `\myletterA` is `\long`, whereas `\cachedata` is defined with `\def` that makes it non `\long`.

Just do

```
\newcommand{\myletterwriter}[1]{\renewcommand*\myletterA{#1}}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks egreg. I do have one more quick question, if I remove the `{}` surrounding `\indenterer` the code breaks with the error "Argument of \read@array has an extra }". Any idea why?

Comment: @Bob The problem are the `&` in the argument to `\readarray` that are mistaken for alignment points. One should plunge in the code of `arrayjobx` for seeing precisely why. On the other hand, I consider the package not more than a toy: there are far better ways for coping with arrays.

Comment: Why do you consider it such? What are the better ways to deal with arrays?

Comment: @Bob Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=arrayjobx+user%3A4427 and some of the linked answers